# Improve speed saving texture to file using Directx 11 c++

Tags: c++, c++11, directx-11

I have a DirectX11 based render, and I need to save a lot of rendered images to hard disk. I have used SaveWICTextureToFile but takes 0.2 seconds to save each image.
Images are saved in resolution 1024x768.

Here it is the code to save the images:

```
    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
                HRESULT hr = _swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(backBuffer.GetAddressOf()));
                throwIfFail(hr, "Unable to get a buffer");
#ifdef LOG
                auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
                wchar_t str[256];
                auto tmp = end;
#endif
                hr = SaveWICTextureToFile(_context.Get(), backBuffer.Get(), GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, w.c_str()/*,&GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA*/);
                //hr = SaveDDSTextureToFile(_context.Get(), backBuffer.Get(), w.c_str()/*,&GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA*/);
#ifdef LOG
                end = high_resolution_clock::now();
                wsprintf(str, L"DXRender::saveLastRenderToFile: %d \n", duration_cast<microseconds>(end - tmp).count());
                OutputDebugString(str);
                tmp = end;
#endif
                throwIfFail(hr, "Unable to save buffer");
```

How can I reduce the time it takes to save each image?

Comment: If you show some code it might be easier to see the problem.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the texture?  Saving textures that occupy a gigabyte of video RAM is naturally going to take longer than saving a 64x64 texture.

Comment: The ``SaveWICToTextureFile`` function in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) is meant for screenshots which are not typically taken every frame. Because it uses "read back" from the frame-buffer, it's going to stall your rendering unless you copy the render texture to some other resource and then maintain many of them instead of blocking further rendering on the call completing.

Comment: The textures are 1024x768

Comment: The problem is that to save textures, you need to create an intermediate Texture to be CPU readable and this take time because of gpu/cpu transfer rate.. So basically, the problem is solved and no other way to do that than using intermediate texture (it is what SaveWICTextureToFile does)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the libJPEG and libPNG libraries to save images, and it work fine and faster than SaveWICToTextureFile, the only trick here is that need to be in account the format of the DirectX texture..
Example:
Texture format: B8G8R8A8
Then to access to each color need to get the n-th 8 bits to get each channel..
This is the only trick here..

Example:

```
auto lastText = _textureDesc;
_inputTexture->GetDesc(&_textureDesc);

unsigned char r, g, b;

int _textureRowSize = _mappedResource.RowPitch / sizeof(unsigned char);

int hIdx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < _textureDesc.Height; ++i)
{
    int wIdx = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < _textureDesc.Width; ++j)
    {
        r = (unsigned char)textPtr[hIdx + wIdx + 2];
        g = (unsigned char)textPtr[hIdx + wIdx + 1];
        b = (unsigned char)textPtr[hIdx + wIdx];
        
        //do whatever you want with this values...
        
        wIdx += 4;
    }
    hIdx += _textureRowSize;
}
```